# Induction proof $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \gt \sqrt{n}$

Tags: analysis

I want to show the following statement through induction for n>1:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \gt \sqrt{n}
$$

The induction step isn't completly working out. I should show that the last term is bigger then sqrt(n+1):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > \sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} 
$$

Any idea?

Comment: Does this work for n = 2?

Comment: Oh, I think you mean an inequality in your original statement (and title), no?

Comment: Trusting that you meant an inequality, you are almost done.  To finish your argument we need to compare your final expression to $\sqrt{n+1}$ but just multiply both by $\sqrt{n+1}$

Comment: That helped. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it should have been an inequality. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geq 2$, $\sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>\sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{2}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^n\,2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)>\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: it is easy to prove $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} > \sqrt{n}$$so it is not a true relation ! look below: 
  suppose $n>1$ 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} >\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} >\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} >\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\...\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ now ,sum of them $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>n*\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: I wanted to show that the bound $\sqrt{n}$ is rather weak, but your solution works marvelously.

Comment: do you look for a sharp bound ?

Comment: Well, it can be easily seen that $2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)< \sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}< 2\sqrt{n}$.  Of course, you can make this bound extremely sharp by introducing terms of order $\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n^2}$, $\ldots$.