# How can I prove this inequality for every natural number $\geq 1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, induction

I've to resolve a inequality using the induction: for every natural number $\geq 1$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \geq \sqrt{n}
$$

At the end, I arrive at this result, but I don't know how I can continue:
$\sqrt{n}+1/\sqrt{n+1} \geq \sqrt{n+1}$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2149448/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1371267/42969.

Comment: I have removed ([tag:proof-verification]) tag, since the post actually contains no proof/solution which is supposed to be checked.

Answer (score 5):

it is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: sorry, i don't have understand...

Comment: since $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ is the smallest summand

Comment: ok, but sorry, i don't understand how can i proove the inequation using that

Comment: we get $n$ summands and $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ is the smallest so your sum is graeter than $$n\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: ahhh ok,i got it, thanks a lot

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: there is a discussion about this answer at [math.meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27031/11206)